Configuring Babel with Yarn Workspaces in React Native: Issues with babelrcRoots Configuration
We want to move our RN project to Yarn Workspaces.
We currently have two different .babelrc.json files for two different packages and from what I've found it requires adding babelrcRoots to the babel.config.js in the root of the project.
But when I am ading it I get the following error:
.babelrcRoots is not allowed in .babelrc or "extends"ed files, only in root programmatic options, or babel.config.js/config file options

I've found this issue in GitHub, but it's old and only has a workaround.
Am I doing something incorrectly or is this just not properly supported in react-native?
